# laravel and sweetalert and rederect to

Tags: ajax, laravel, redirect, sweetalert

i use laravel 5.8 and i have a a problem if i insert or update a page than i go not back to the page list.

postcontroller :
i use :         `return response()->json('Post Created');`
and i use a ajax file whit this code :

```js
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: this.action,
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,

            success: function(response){ 
                
                Sweet('success',response)
                
                success(response)

            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) 
            {
                $('.errorarea').show();
                $.each(xhr.responseJSON.errors, function (key, item) 
                {
                    Sweet('error',item)
                    $("#errors").html("<li class='text-danger'>"+item+"</li>")
                });
                errosresponse(xhr, status, error);
            }
        })


    });
```

i get a nice message if it is insert or updated but it not go back to my list, hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: i cant understand that problem please say what you got and what you expect

Comment: after inserd or update i do not go back to the list ( url post/index

Comment: that is because you are using ajax. when you use ajax page doesn't redirect any more if you want to redirect after success you have to do it manually. fo you want to redirect manually?

Comment: ooo okay, i dont wanne do it manual, it can not automatic after submit success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to redirect after success do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: this.action,
        data: new FormData(this),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,

        success: function(response){ 
            
            Sweet('success',response)
            
            success(response)
            window.location.href = "url you want to redirect to";

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) 
        {
            $('.errorarea').show();
            $.each(xhr.responseJSON.errors, function (key, item) 
            {
                Sweet('error',item)
                $("#errors").html("<li class='text-danger'>"+item+"</li>")
            });
            errosresponse(xhr, status, error);
        }
    })


});
```